# Laws of logic literature recommendations

Tags: logic, reference-request, philosophy-of-logic

What are some books/papers/articles I could read to develop an informed perspective on questions like "where do the laws of logic come from? Do they have a deep connection with the structure of reality or not? What is the relationship between thought and logic? Would an alien species have the same logic as us?" etc

Comment: Stephen Read: Thinking About Logic is an excellent intro to the philosophy of logic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [References for the justification of the use of Logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39956/references-for-the-justification-of-the-use-of-logic)

Comment: WVO Quine, [Philosophy of Logic (1986)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Logic_2nd_Edition/GxlUEyI-6JoC), Ian Rumfitt, [The Boundary Stones of Thought ; An Essay in the Philosophy of Logic (2015)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Boundary_Stones_of_Thought/R_EkBwAAQBAJ) and M.Dummett, [The Logical Basis of Metaphysics (1991)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Logical_Basis_of_Metaphysics/lvsVFxK3BPcC)

Comment: @Conifold yes, that works